# Is a String part of another String in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, uisearchbar, searchbar

I programmed a Search Bar in Swift. Now I need to check if the searched Word is part of a Word in my Array

Example :

```
Search: hel   - word in array: hello --> true    
Search: bs -  word in array: hello --> false
```

And is there a way to check that I only get true when the Search is the beginning of the Word in my Array --

Example:

```
Search: hel -  word in array: hello --> true   
Search: lo  - word in array: hello --> false
```

Sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: "hello" contains "lo", does it not? I think that last result should be `true`

Comment: @oltman read the question again. ronny is asking if he can match the beginning of the word. Hence the `lo` -> `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do exactly what you want, I assumed that you ensure that the input and the word form your array is a valid string. Using startIndex and endIndex is recommended to get proper glyph counting in a String in Swift and you can easily refer to a part of a string by using brackets:

```
var input = "hel"
let wordInArray = "hello"

if wordInArray[input.startIndex..<input.endIndex] == input {
  println(true)
} else {
  println(false)
}
```

this will evaluate to true when the input is "hel" and gives false in case of "lo"

(depending from your spec, you must check if the length of the search input is less or equal to the word in the Array or use min(input.endIndex,wordInArray.endIndex) at the max value of the range to prevent error)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C there was a function for finding locations of characters in NSStrings.  `rangeOfString:`.  In swift, from what I've found, it's

```
var range = text.rangeOfString("your-string");
if(range.startIndex == 0)
    //This was found at the very beginning of the text string
```

Work with that code a bit and you will be able to find the location of the found string inside the searched string.